# React - SUM state values

Tags: reactjs, forms

EDIT: I forgot to say that the onChange on the inputs doesn't work, how do I tell to onChange it's the state value inside the group?

I started to learn React few weeks ago. I want to SUM the group state values and every time it changes the total value changes too. I'm using material ui to create the form. The problem is if I change the state value to int the FormControlLabel value won't work... as a string the total doesn't work as expectable. And how I can handle the total change everytime I change the option?

Thanks in advance.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      total: 0,
      group: {
        feedingGroup: "3",
        bathingA: "3",
        bathingB: "3",
      }
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ total: this.calculateTotal(this.state.group) });
  }

  calculateTotal = (values) => {
    return Object.entries(values).reduce((finalValue, [key, value]) => {
      return finalValue + value;
    }, 0);
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <FormControl component="fieldset" error="" className="">

          <RadioGroup aria-label="quiz" name="quiz" value={this.state.group.feedingGroup}
            onChange={(value) => { this.setState({ feedingGroup: (value.target.value) }); }}>
            <FormControlLabel value="0" control={<Radio />} label="Op1" />
            <FormControlLabel value="1" control={<Radio />} label="Op2" />
            <FormControlLabel value="2" control={<Radio />} label="Op3" />
            <FormControlLabel value="3" control={<Radio />} label="Op4" />
          </RadioGroup>

          <RadioGroup aria-label="quiz" name="quiz" value={this.state.group.bathingA}
            onChange={(value) => { this.setState({ bathingA: (value.target.value) }); }}>
            <FormControlLabel value="0" control={<Radio />} label="Op1" />
            <FormControlLabel value="1" control={<Radio />} label="Op2" />
            <FormControlLabel value="2" control={<Radio />} label="Op3" />
            <FormControlLabel value="3" control={<Radio />} label="Op4" />
          </RadioGroup>

          <Button type="submit" variant="outlined" color="primary" className="">
            Check Answer
        </Button>
          <FormHelperText>{this.state.total}</FormHelperText>
        </FormControl>
      </form>

    );
  }

}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about casting the value:

```
calculateTotal = (values) => {
  return Object.entries(values).reduce((finalValue, [key, value]) => {
    return finalValue + Number(value);
  }, 0);
}
```

Comment: I din't know about that Number cast. I tried parseInt but it didn't worked. And how about handle the change value and update the total? Thanks by the way.